# Периодичеки пропадает соединение, через Samba

Tags: linux, ssh, centos7, samba

У меня домашний сервер на CentOS 7.6. Периодически пропадает доступ к серверу, через Samba с рабочей станции под Linux При перезагрузке в Windows доступ к серверу есть, но затянутый по времени до 30 секунд, против 0,5 секунды при нормальной работе сервера. То же самое и при попытке соединения, через SSH. Когда сервер работает нормально, соединение и из Putty, и из Dolphin происходит за 0,5 секунды. Когда пропадает  соединение, через Samba, доступ через SSH также затягивается до 30 секунд. Работа сервера Samba может восстановиться после нескольких перезагрузок, может и не восстановиться и приходится восстанавливать систему с ранее созданного образа. Если необходимы дополнительные сведения, скажите, какие. Я последовательно выполнил команды `systemctl status smb nmb`, `firewall-cmd --list-all`, `getsebool -a | grep -E "smb|samba"`, `getsebool -a | grep -E "ssh"`, ответы команд при нормальной работе и отсутствии доступа, отличаются только временем.

Comment: По Wi-Fi что ли ходите на сервер? Если нет, то Wireshark в помощь!

Comment: Исходя из описания проблемы, похоже что проблема кроется в работе системы, в момент когда проблема есть, посмотрите что запущено на сервере командой top или htop(улучшенная версия команды top). Полезной информацией будут количество ядер `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu cores"` и load average

Comment: На сервер захожу, через локальную сеть. Временно решил проблему отключением на сервере менеджера настройки сети (Network Manager), на одном из англоязычных сайтов нашёл такую рекомендацию. Также полностью отключил сетевой протокол ipv6 и клиентскую службу dhcpv6-client. Пока работоспособность восстановилась, хотя не знаю на сколько.

Comment: В Windows  я использую для подключение имя сервера, типа \\srvnik\home\, а в Linux подключаюсь по IP адресу.

Comment: Проблема не решена. Сегодня утром включил сервер и снова из Linux не могу подключиться к серверу, через Самбу. Всё то же самое, один в один. Как будто centos специально настроена на такую работу, только непонятно, по какому графику работает Самба, может работать один день, может два, может неделю. И не работает тоже по такому же "расписанию".

Comment: Изменения, всё-таки, есть. Из Windows  отклик сервера стал практически мгновенным.

Comment: К этой проблеме добавилась ещё одна, о которой я уже начал забывать, CentOS "с какого то перепугу" переводит один, или несколько примонтированных дисков в режим "Только чтение". Возможно эти проблемы взаимосвязаны. После перезагрузки сервера в Windows все диски оказались нормальными.

Comment: Примерно неделю назад снёс CentOS 7.6 и установил на сервер Ubuntu18.04.2 server. все проблемы моментально пропали, что интересно, все настройки и конфигурационные файлы просто перенёс с CentOS, конечно, пришлось поплясать с бубном, когда настраивал iptables, уже привык к Firewalld, но система работает, за неделю ни одного сбоя. Ubuntu в очередной не оправдала моих предубеждений и по скорости работы нисколько не хуже, чем CentOS. Установил и на USB_HDD десктопа Ubuntu 19.04 Plasma, пока работает не хуже чем Fedora.

Comment: Сейчас я использую на сервере две системы, расположенные на разных физических дисках. Примерно неделю в CentOS была проблема с Samba, а вчера, при очередном включении сервера, проблема исчезла. Когда проблема появляется, время отклика сервера при соединении, через Putty, (с момента запуска Putty до приглашения ввести логин) увеличивается с 1 секунды до 40 секунд, время запуска Midnight Commander на сервере также увеличивается до 40 секунд. Самое интересное в том, что если примонтировать сетевые диски, через fstab, то соединение с ресурсом сервера происходит мгновенно и не пропадает.

Answer (score 0):

Наконец нашёл причину нестабильной работы Samba на домашнем сервере. Она оказалась в сотовом роутере Huawei B310. Я использовал его в качестве основного сервера DNS  в CentOS, а он "заточен" под Windows, отсюда и нестабильная работа. Временно решил проблему путём использования публичного DNS сервера из интернет. Сейчас изучаю встроенный в CentOS сервер DNS bind, когда разберусь буду подключать и настраивать.

Проблема решена установкой на сервер Rosa Fresh R11, теперь  соединение с интернет не зависит от наличия интернет. Очевидно, это такое свойство CentOS, требующее для работы сети соединение с интернет, другим просто объяснить это не могу.

После очередного обновления Rosa Fresh рухнула, просто перестала загружаться. Видно в НТЦ ИТ Роса, что-то "накосячили". Восстанавливать систему не захотел, просто установил на сервер CentOS 8.1 и, как ни странно, удалось всё настроить, только без подключения к интернет, ресурсы сервера открываются за 1 - 2 секунды, против 0,1 секунды, когда соединение есть, и это уже вполне приемлемо.

Comment: Протокол DNS абсолютно стандартен и одинаков что для Linux, что для Windows. Поэтому DNS сервер никак не может быть "заточен" под линукс или виндовс. А вот не настроенным он вполне себе может быть.

Comment: Я имел в виду тот факт, что под Windows "заточен" роутер Huawei B310, цитата "Наконец нашёл причину нестабильной работы Samba на домашнем сервере. Она оказалась в сотовом роутере Huawei B310." Однако, сейчас я уверен практически на 100%, что дело в CentOS 7. Примерно 4 месяца назад я установил CentOS 8 и проблема решилась сама собой. Теперь при наличии соединения с интернет ресурсы сервера открываются за доли секунды, а при отсутствии соединения с интернет, за 1 - 2 секунды, а это уже вполне приемлемо.

Comment: От проблемы избавился на 100% установкой на сервер Debian 10. Доступ к ресурсам samba абсолютно не зависит от наличия соединения с интернет. Стало быть дело было всё-таки в операционной системе сервера.